# Why did I get -2 reputation without telling me why?

Tags: support, reputation, user-accounts

my reputation was 910 and when I refresh the page It becames 908, I have checked the `achievement` and `INBOX` and no reason is mentioned?

Note: this happened to me several times this week, even when I didn't do anything at all.
and it start to happend when I reach 900

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The -2 you lost were because a question you had edited (which gained you +2) was deleted by the author. When a question is deleted, the reputation changes associated with it are reversed as happened here.

You also lost -4 reputation a couple of days ago because 2 questions you had edited were migrated away from the site because they were off topic.

Another -4 came a few days before that when two questions you had edited were deleted. One by the OP and the other by [the system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/203101) since it had been closed and had attracted no votes for more than 9 days.

Unfortunately, since deleted posts are only visible to >10k rep users, your profile doesn't show this information. You might be able to see the migrated ones but not the deleted ones.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I thought it is a bug or something like that.